# How to make a wireless network forget my device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Im currently staying at a hotel, and the wi fi here is one of those that has no password initially but once you connect, a page pops up and asks for user and password (room number, last name). The wi fi really sucks so I called to the lobby and told them about it. They told me to try to relogin and instead of choosing the Guest option, to choose the Events option and gave me a different name and password. I tried forgetting the network on my devices, I also tried spoofing my mac addres on my macbook but non of it seems to work. When I choose the network from the list it automatically connects, I dont get the pop up where I could choose the options anymore. Is there a way for me to make the network forget my devices so I can relogin? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: It's not the network remembering your device, rather your device remembering the network

Comment: Depending on the OS (and you should add this info to your posts) you generally open up WIFI network settings, right click/highlight the relevant AP and delete it.

Comment: But I already tried forgetting the network tho and still doesn't work

Comment: try private/incognito mode on your browser, in case its your browser

Comment: Most captive portals actually identify by your MAC address and/or IP address, so you don’t have to enter your credentials after every small connection drop. There is nothing you can do about that except staying disconnected for a long enough time.

Answer (score 0):

These access points are called **captive portals**(no wireless security, but require login through a browser).

Apple recognizes such access points and it sounds like it is trying to re-authenticate you automatically based on the authentication you used the first time.

You can read more information about [captive portals and using them on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45418/how-to-automatically-login-to-captive-portals-on-os-x).

Comment: If it's trying to authenticate via browser, Maybe clearing browser's history, cache and data will do.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus By default it looks like OSX uses a special browser to do the login and you don't get easy access to the special browser settings to clear anything.